# Displaying QML Item over a QWidget

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qt5, qtwidgets

I want to make an application that will benefit both from OpenGL and QML advantages. I want to use `QOpenGLWidget` and place QML `Item` over it. `Item` will be partially transparent. I though it may be possible by using `QQuickView` but I just figured out that it does cover all transparent parts with black color. An attempt to achieve what I need (an example project) may be found on my GitHub [here](https://github.com/fhazubski/QQuickViewFlickerProblem).

Is it possible to render QML `Item` with all children onto an existing `QWidget` in such way that it is visible under `Item`, wherever `Item` is not completely opaque?

I guess that in the worst case scenario I could create bitmaps from the `QWidget` and the `Item` objects, somehow combine and display them but I seek easier way. If there is no easier way I could just never display those two at the same time.

The reason why I do not want to use OpenGL features in QML directly is [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50493). Maybe I should just use the work around mentioned in the link.

Comment: Have you tried QQuickWidget? It's supposed to be a much better alternative to the problematic window containers.

Comment: @J-PNurmi Thanks. I did not try it before. I will check this out and let you know

Comment: You can render custom OpenGL inside a qtquick view without the need of using any widgets

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld This sounds like a very good idea also. What classes/objects would I need?

Comment: Iirc you can either integrate the rendering with the QQuickView or implement your custom QQuickItem. Don't have the details handy and can't search right now.

Comment: This will give you an idea and actual code: https://advancingusability.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/how-to-integrate-ogre3d-into-a-qt5-qml-scene/ . I'm not entirely sure, but it seems this is what you want (look at the control box in the right side of the video)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need Widgets for it. You can do custom rendering in QtQuick using [QQuickFramebufferObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickframebufferobject.html) class. I used to do it before, though don't have code anymore. This article seems to explain what to do https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/05/11/integrating-custom-opengl-rendering-with-qt-quick-via-qquickframebufferobject/